# Jquery compare the height of to divs

Tags: jquery, loops

I want compare the height of to div and append side add while the side div get the same size off the other div, but my code get a infinity loop.

```
//the i var its just for testing with a non infinity loop
var i = 0;
while($('#lista-body').height() > $('#ads-side').height() && i < 10){
    $.post("getADSSide.php" , { cliente: '<?=$clienteCrypt?>' }, function(data){            
        if (data != '' || data != undefined || data != null){
            setTimeout(function(){ $('#ads-side').append(data);}, 1000);
        }
    });
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Won't `#lista-body` height always be greater than `#ads-side` height? You aren't appending to `#lista-body`.

Comment: @CharlieFish listBody = 10, adsSide = 0.  Add 20 to adsSide. Recheck the comparison.

Comment: @Draco18s How do you know listBody = 10, and adsSide = 0?? And how do you know it's adding 20 to adsSide??

Comment: @Draco18s Nothing in the question mentions any of that.

Comment: @CharlieFish arbitrary numbers to prove that your comment is verifiably false.  Adding height to #ads-side until #ads-Side is taller *will eventually happen.*

Comment: @Draco18s You are completely right. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Ajax runs after the loop completes.

> Synchronous execution means that the client waits for the method to complete execution and return its results before executing the next JavaScript statement or evaluating the next term of an expression.
>
> Asynchronous execution means that immediately after the client calls the method, it continues to execute the next JavaScript statement or to evaluate the next term of an expression whether or not the asynchronous method completes and returns results.

From the [Progress Data Objects Guide and Reference](https://documentation.progress.com/output/pdo/index.html#page/pdo/asynchronous-and-synchronous-execution.html)

Ajax (`$.post`, or more specifically, the *callback function*) is an asynchronous action. You are essentially attempting to use synchronous code to wait on an asynchronous action, which will never work (or if it does, it will do so very badly). Especially as your synchronous code continues to execute further asynchronous Ajax instructions.

If you want to fill the div until its height is sufficient, calculate the height inside the callback, and if there is not enough content, re-execute the Ajax call:

```
function fillAds() {
    $.post("getADSSide.php" , { cliente: '<?=$clienteCrypt?>' }, function(data){            
        if (data != '' || data != undefined || data != null){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#ads-side').append(data);
                if($('#lista-body').height() > $('#ads-side').height()) {
                    fillAds();
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
}
```

With another `fillAds();` call somewhere external to this code.

Notice also, that by making this simple change, in the event that the asynchronous action *fails* (e.g. data is undefined, empty, null, or the method fails to execute entirely) we don't attempt to make further Ajax calls. Huzzah! Free error handling!